# How to implement lapply function in R using package "sparklyr"

Tags: r, apache-spark, parallel-processing, sparklyr, mclapply

I am pretty new to Spark, I have tried to look for something on the web but I haven't found anything satisfactory.

I have always run parallel computations using the command `mclapply` and I like its structure (i.e., first parameter used as scrolling index, second argument the function to be parallelized, and then other optional parameters passed to the function).
Now I am trying to do kind of the same thing via Spark, i.e., I would like to distribute my computations among all the node of the Spark cluster. This is shortly what I have learned and how I think the code should be structured (I'm using the package `sparklyr`):

1. I create a connection to Spark using the command `spark_connect`;
2. I copy my data.frame in the Spark environment with `copy_to` and access it through its tibble;
3. I would like to implement a "Spark-friendly" version of `mclapply`, but I have seen there is no similar function in the package (I have seen there exists the function `spark.lapply` in the `SparkR` package, but unfortunately it is not in the CRAN anymore).

Here below, a simple test script I have implemented that works using the function `mclapply`.

```
#### Standard code that works with mclapply #########
dfTest = data.frame(X = rep(1, 10000), Y = rep(2, 10000))

.testFunc = function(X = 1, df, str) {
    rowSelected = df[X, ]
    y = as.numeric(rowSelected[1] + rowSelected[2])
    return(list(y = y, str = str))
}

lOutput = mclapply(X = 1 : nrow(dfTest), FUN = .testFunc, df = dfTest, 
                   str = "useless string", mc.cores = 2)

######################################################

###### Similar code that should work with Spark ######
library(sparklyr)
sc = spark_connect(master = "local")

dfTest = data.frame(X = rep(1, 10000), Y = rep(2, 10000))

.testFunc = function(X = 1, df, str) {
  rowSelected = df[X, ]
  nSum = as.numeric(rowSelected[1] + rowSelected[2])
  return(list(nSum = nSum, str = str))
}

dfTest_tbl = copy_to(sc, dfTest, "test_tbl", overwrite = TRUE)

# Apply similar function mclapply to dfTest_tbl, that works with 
# Spark
# ???
######################################################
```

If someone has already found a solution for this, then it will be great. Also other references/guides/links are more than welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**sparklyr**

`spark_apply` is existing function you're looking for:

```
spark_apply(sdf, function(data) {
   ...
})
```

Please refer to [Distributed R](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr#distributed-r) in `sparklyr` documentation for details.

**SparkR**

With SparkR use `gapply` / `gapplyCollect`

```
gapply(df, groupingCols, function(data) {...} schema)
```

`dapply` / `dapplyCollect`

```
dapply(df, function(data) {...}, schema)
```

UDFs. Refer to

- [`dapply` docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/dapply.html)
- [`gapply` docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/gapply.html)

for details.

Be warned that all solutions are inferior compared to native Spark code and should be avoided when high performance is required.

Comment: The function `spark_apply` is not appropriate since it takes only one argument in input, and does not maintain the same structure of `mclapply`.
`spark_apply` seems to be good if one wants to apply simple functions over the rows of a spark data.frame. In my case, I find difficult to parallelize a function with more than one input (for example, a function that takes as input a data.frame, a vector, a string, a matrix, etc.)

`SparkR` might be more useful, but for deployment purposes, since it is not CRAN-mantained anymore, it is not a possible solution for me.

Comment: _Be warned that all solutions are inferior compared to native Spark code and should be avoided when high performance is required_, thanks for your suggestion. Do you have a good reference/guide where to start?

Comment: Keep in mind the context argument in spark_apply, you can pass in extra variables that way. To pass in multiple variables (beyond just the one allowed by the simple function) you can set context={c(y<-yourVector, z<-"yourString", a<-yourMatrix). You just have to unpack these values inside of the function.

Answer (score 2):

`sparklyr::spark_apply` now can support pass some external variables like models as context.

Here is my example to run xgboost model on sparklyr:

```
bst <- xgboost::xgb.load("project/models/xgboost.model")
res3 <- spark_apply(x = ft_union_price %>% sdf_repartition(partitions = 1500, partition_by = "uid"),
                   f = inference_fn,
                   packages = F,
                   memory = F,
                   names = c("uid",
                               "action_1",
                               "pred"), 
                   context = {model <- bst})
```